# Expression Engine 2 301 redirect old template group to new one

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, expressionengine

I thought this would be pretty simple, however I am having issues permanently redirecting an old template group to a new one.

I have `www.domain.co.uk/weddings` which needs to be directed to `www.domain.co.uk/more-weddings`.

Both template groups exist, not sure if I need to delete the old one too? Or any other settings in the template preferences?

Here's what I have been trying to use:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/weddings\$ http://www.domain.co.uk/more-weddings
```

I have a load more redirects which are working too, does this new one need to be placed above them?

Comment: Why do you have dollar special symbol escaped `\$` ?? This tells Apache to look for this URL `/weddings$`. With no back slash before `$` Apache will look for `/weddings` exactly.

Answer (score 3):

You could enable PHP in the older template (weddings/index) and place this in it:

```
<?php
    header('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently');
    header('Location: http://www.domain.co.uk/more-weddings');
    exit();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

When writing `mod_rewrite` rules, the rules get applied in the order that they appear.

In your case, you'd want your `RedirectMatch` to **appear before any other rewrite rules** — this is especially true if you're [removing index.php from your ExpressionEngine URLs](http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/general/remove_index.php.html).

In your example, if you only want to redirect a *certain directory* (i.e. an ExpressionEngine template group), the following rule will do so, while allowing the rest of the site to function normally:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Only Matching Directories
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(weddings|weddings/.*)$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.co.uk/more-weddings/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

**Make sure this rule appears *before* your removal of index.php** (example below):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Only Matching Directories
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(weddings|weddings/.*)$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.co.uk/more-weddings/$1 [R=301,L]

    # Removes ExpressionEngine index.php from URLs
    RewriteCond $1 !\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

If you want Google and other crawlers to see your content as temporarily moved (Response code 302, the default) or permanently moved (301), be sure to configure the [RewriteRule Flags](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.3/rewrite/flags.html) appropriately.

[image: Apache mod_rewrite Cheat Sheet]